# C# DataGridView dynamic gradient

Tags: c#, uitableview, dynamic, datagridview

Good day!

I have read a lot about dynamic cells back color changing, but have not found the resolve of my problem. 
In my project, I used 32x32 DataGridView. All values are integer, also I've changed default cell format to Numeric.

This code makes gradient painting without any problem:

```
void AFRTableGraient()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewTAF.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridViewTAF.RowCount; j++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dataGridViewTAF.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null)
                {
                    break;
                }

                dataGridViewTAF.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0x10 + (int)dataGridViewTAF.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value, 0x88 + (int)dataGridViewTAF.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value, 0x88 + (int)dataGridViewTAF.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
            }
            catch
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    dataGridViewTAF.Update();
    dataGridViewTAF.Refresh();
}
```

But I need to change cell color after value changed.

I've used CellFormatting, KeyDown, CellLeave, CellPainting, Enter, etc, events, but has no result.
When I tried to use CellPainting method, the app is freeze, but update the color is not happening.
Also, I've tried to use the "timer", but still nothing.

I know, there is a simple way of resolving, but I need help to found it.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you want to _” change cell color after value changed”_ … have you tried wiring up the grids `CellValueChanged` event? In addition, it appears the `i` and `j` variables are backwards. The variable `i` is looping through the columns, and the variable `j` is looping through the rows, however, the reference to the grid cell using these indexes appears backwards… `dataGridViewTAF.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value…`?

Comment: Yes, man, I tried to use this method, but it didn't work, cell color not changed... Seems that I have to redraw the DataGridView itself, but I've used Update and Refresh method for it (as I listed above) - still nothing...

Comment: I suggest posting the `CellValueChanged` event you tried. In my tests… the `CellValueChanged` event successfully changed the cell color. I am confident from what you describe that the `CellValueChanged` event is the event you want to use for this. Example, some events like “painting” get fired often and it would appear to me that this (setting the cell color) would be unnecessary since the value of the cell has not changed. My tests using the `CellValueChanged` event to change the cells color worked successfully.

Comment: Also, it is not clear what the exact values are in the grid, however there are many, many values that will cause the `Color.FromArgb(…)` to fail and throw an exception. It is unwise to NOT check these values BEFORE you call the `Color.FromArgb` method. The method will throw an `ArgumentException` if any of the alpha, red, green, or blue parameters is less than 0 or greater that 255.